# Diagonal Borders on side of div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two divs right next to each other with diagonal borders on the side.

I made a very rough layout.

[image]

I already came up with an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/4vnankfj/1/.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  background: orange;
}
.right p {
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently my problems are that the right side covers the left side. The text on the left should adapt to the diagonal border.
Furthermore I want the right side to be completely orange.

Is it possible to achieve that ?

Comment: Something like https://jsfiddle.net/4vnankfj/2/ ?  it's not flexible tho

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4vnankfj/4/ it may helpful